# Convert parquet to list of objects in python

Tags: python, pandas, parquet

I am reading a parquet file with panda:

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_parquet('myfile.parquet', engine='pyarrow')
```

The file has the following structure:

|  | company_id | user_id | attribute_name | attribute_value | timestamp |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 116664 | 111f07000612 | first_name | Tom | 2022-03-23 17:11:58 |
| 2 | 116664 | 111f07000612 | last_name | Cruise | 2022-03-23 17:11:58 |
| 3 | 116664 | 111f07000612 | city | New York | 2022-03-23 17:11:58 |
| 4 | 116664 | abcf0700d009d122 | first_name | Matt | 2022-02-23 10:11:59 |
| 5 | 116664 | abcf0700d009d122 | last_name | Damon | 2022-02-23 10:11:59 |

I would like to group by user_id and generate a list of objects (that will be stored as json) with the following format:

```json
[
 {
   "user_id": "111f07000612",
   "first_name": "Tom",
   "last_name": "Cruise",
   "city": "New York"
 },
 {
   "user_id": "abcf0700d009d122",
   "first_name": "Matt",
   "last_name": "Damon"
 }
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi  Hope you are doing well!

You can achieve it with something similar to this

```py
from pprint import pprint

import pandas as pd


# because I don't have the exact parquet file, I will just mock it
# df = pd.read_parquet("myfile.parquet", engine="pyarrow")
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "company_id": [116664, 116664, 116664, 116664, 116664],
        "user_id": ["111f07000612", "111f07000612", "111f07000612", "abcf0700d009d122", "abcf0700d009d122"],
        "attribute_name": ["first_name", "last_name", "city", "first_name", "last_name"],
        "attribute_value": ["Tom", "Cruise", "New York", "Matt", "Damon"],
        "timestamp": ["2022-03-23 17:11:58", "2022-03-23 17:11:58", "2022-03-23 17:11:58", "2022-03-23 17:11:58", "2022-03-23 17:11:58"]
    }
)

records = []

for user_id, group in df.groupby("user_id"):
    transformed_group = (
        group[["attribute_name", "attribute_value"]]
        .set_index("attribute_name")
        .transpose()
        .assign(user_id=user_id)
    )
    rercord, *_ = transformed_group.to_dict("records")
    records.append(rercord)

pprint(records)
# [{'city': 'New York',
#   'first_name': 'Tom',
#   'last_name': 'Cruise',
#   'user_id': '111f07000612'},
#  {'first_name': 'Matt', 'last_name': 'Damon', 'user_id': 'abcf0700d009d122'}]
```